# symplectic sructure on a ball

Tags: symplectic-geometry

We know by Darboux theorem that any symplectic form on a manifold $W^{2n}$ is locally symplectomorophic to the standard symplectic form $dx\wedge dy$ on $R^{2n}$. Is it true that any symplectic form on a ball $B^{2n}$ of arbitrary radius is symplectomorphic to the standard one? or -I guess equivalently- can we extend this local symplectomorphsim as long as we stay on a ball   (say handles of different indices in a Morse decomposition of the manifold) in the manifold $W^{2n}$?

Comment: No. Symplectic volume is a global invariant and it changes as the radius of the ball changes.

Comment: Gromov showed that there are symplectic structures on $\mathbb R^{2n}$ such that they are not the pullback under an embedding $\mathbb R^{2n}\to\mathbb R^{2n}$ of the standard symplectic form (priovided $n>1$)